# proper way of displaying error messages

Tags: python, exception, logging

According to [Python's Logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), `logging.error` is to be used to "report suppression of an error without raising an exception.", whereas if I wanted to report an error I'm supposed to just raise an exception and not use `logging` at all.

What if I want to report an error and then raise an exception?

For example:

```
try:                                                                        
    os.path.getsize('/nonexistent')                                         
except os.error as error:                                                   
    logging.error(str(error))                                               
    logging.error('something went wrong')                                   
    raise SystemExit(1)
```

This results in the following lines being printed to the standard error:

```
ERROR:root:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/nonexistent'
ERROR:root:something went wrong
```

It seems sensible.  Or:

```
try:                                                                        
    os.path.getsize('/nonexistent')                                         
except os.error as error:                                                   
    logging.error(str(error))                                               
    raise SomeUserDefinedException('something went wrong')
```

Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

- `logging` is used to report.
- `raise` is an action which interrupts the normal flow of the program.

Typically, you `raise` exceptions where there is an actual flow to interrupt, and when you want to report, you can use `logging`, which will log errors and exceptions by default.

The `logging` part usually comes as a wrapper around a module, class, or middleware in your program.

`logging` within the code should only be used for **DEBUG** purposes, or for **INFO** purpose if you wanted to keep track of some information in your server logs for example. Not for **ERROR**.

Comment: So what does one is supposed to use for reporting errors?

Comment: you should have logging setup globally to catch any errors and exceptions, and it will display the exception message you set in the `raise` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that is a bad practice.  Exceptions and logging serve two different purposes and in any given situation you may want one, the other or both.  Exceptions are for programmatic consumption and control flow within your code, while logging is for external consumption, by either a human or some sort of automated log watcher (Splunk for example).  For instance, you may log the values of certain variables to help you figure out what happened and improve the code, though in that case, a level of debug would be more appropriate.  Or you may want a systems administrator to be aware of the issue and potentially take some action.  In that case, setting the log level to error and using something like a syslog logging handler makes sense.